# Simple for loop doesen't work in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a matrix (called configmatrix) and I have written a for loop in python to sum its elements. This is my code:

```
def magnetic (l):
M = 0
for i in range (l):                           
    for j in range (l):
        M = M + configmatrix[i][j]
    return M
```

But I get this error message:
[image: error]
I don't know what is the problem with my code.

Comment: Your function definition isn't indented.

Comment: The error message couldn't be more clear...

Comment: Probably a bug in Python. Has anyone checked whether `for` is still working today?

Answer (score 4):

You need to indent your function body like this:

```
 def magnetic (l):
    M = 0
    for i in range (l):                           
        for j in range (l):
            M = M + configmatrix[i][j]
    return M
```